# Primefaces, selectOneMenu -> listen to "no matching elements for filter"

Tags: primefaces, selectonemenu

I have a selectOneMenu with `filter="true"` option.

After entering some characters in the filter input field, the selection list is filtered, the first matching element is marked yellow and IS SELECTED. OK, but after entering some more characters so that there are no matches any more, the selected element is still there (so, set in my bean).

I want to have the behavior: if I enter a string that do not match with any elements, the selection should be removed.

How can I listen to something like "no matchers any more" -> then I can set my bean property also to null.

Comment: Afaik, auto selection is not the default. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info